# Kanban board in TFS 2012 RTM

Tags: tfs, kanban, tfs-2012

Is possible to add kanban board to TFS 2012 web access site like is on TFS Service ?
If yes how cvan i add it to web access site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to wait for the update which is due this autumn.

From Brian Harry's [Blog post announcing Kanban](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/08/13/introducing-kanban.aspx) support:

> I also wanted to mention that our plan is to include the kanban support in our first TFS 2012 on premises update later this fall.